# joining big files in Python

Tags: python, chunks, merge-file

I have several HEVEC files that I'd like to merge. With small files (about 1.5 GB) the following code works fine

```
with open(path+"/"+str(sys.argv[2])+"_EL.265", "wb") as outfile:
        for fname in dirs:
                with open(path+"/"+fname, 'rb') as infile:
                    outfile.write(infile.read())
```

With bigger files (8 GB or more) the same code get stuck.
I've copied from here ([Lazy Method for Reading Big File in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python)) the code to read big files in chunks and I've integrated it with my code:

```
def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1024):
    """Lazy function (generator) to read a file piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""
    while True:
        data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data


with open(path + "/" + str(sys.argv[2]) + "_BL.265", "wb") as outfile_bl:
        for fname in dirs:
                    with open(path+"/"+fname, 'rb') as infile:
                            for piece in read_in_chunks(infile):
                                outfile_bl.write(infile.read())
```

This code produces a file that is of the right size but it is no longer an HEVC file and cannot be read by a video player.

Any Idea?
Please help

Dario

Comment: `read_in_chunks` is already reading from the file; calling `infile.read` isn't necessary. You just want to call `outfile_bl.write(piece)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading from `infile` in two different places: inside `read_in_chunks`, and directly when you call `outfile_bl`. This causes you to skip writing the data just read into the variable `piece`, so you only copy roughly half the file.

You've already read data into `piece`; just write that to your file.

```
with open(path + "/" + str(sys.argv[2]) + "_BL.265", "wb") as outfile_bl:
    for fname in dirs:
        with open(path+"/"+fname, 'rb') as infile:
            for piece in read_in_chunks(infile):
                outfile_bl.write(piece)
```

---

As an aside, you don't really need to define `read_in_chunks`, or at least its definition can be simplified greatly by using `iter`:

```
def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1024):
    """Lazy function (generator) to read a file piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""

    yield from iter(lambda: file_object.read(chunk_size), '')

    # Or
    # from functools import partial
    # yield from iter(partial(file_object.read, chunk_size), '')
```